# Error installing the Expo CLI, running command "npm install expo-cli --global"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation, expo, command-line-interface

I'm trying to start a React Native application, But when I try to install the Expo CLI running any of the commands below, it returns this error:

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amro\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-21T18_29_03_950Z-debug-0.log

Commands tried:
"npm install expo-cli --global"
"npm install --global expo-cli"
"npm install expo-cli --location=global"

If anybody has any suggestion on how to install the Expo CLI, I would very much appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: What version of node/npm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing without the global tag?

```
npm install expo-cli
```

I started a blank project and this worked fine.

Triple check you are in the correct file location when running the command. If you are new to expo/npm/etc, double check you are using correct versions of Node.js and Npm, as well as having correctly set up environment variables. Please reply to this comment if this doesn't work and you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

As of Expo v46 the CLI is part of the local expo package. There is no need to install the global package.

Use `npx expo start` to start your app.
`npx` will look in the `node_modules` of your current directory first, and because the expo package includes the expo-cli bin it will be invoked.

This makes maintaining older apps MUCH easier.
Details in the blog post.

[The New Expo CLI](https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421)
[image: blog image]